# Angular chaching/store datos obtenidos de servicios

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs

Estoy escribiendo una aplicación con Angular para la gestión de fotos (para aprender Angular) que consume todos los datos de una API RESTful y tengo el siguiente problema:

El listado de álbumes tarda en cargar un par de segundos. Cuando entro a un álbum se cargan todas las fotos y se muestran. Ahora bien, cuando vuelvo al listado de álbumes se vuelven a cargar y hay que esperar otra vez un par de segundos cuando podrían estar cacheados los datos o algo así.

¿Hay alguna forma de conseguir que los álbumes se guardaran en una caché o store y solo se vuelvan a cargar si hay nuevos álbumes en el servidor? ¿Cuál es la forma genuina en Angular de lograr esto? ¿Que se comporte como Google Fotos donde al entrar en un álbum y salir el listado de álbumes es como si estuviera ya cargado de antes?

Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes simplemente guardar el resultado en un atributo de tu servicio tras la primera vez que buscas los datos y a partir de ahí devolver ese valor. Si lo quieres más a largo plazo podrías usar el `localStorage`. No hay más magia

Comment: Ok, gracias... probaré así. Pensaba que habría lagún "truco" para hacer esto en Angular.

Comment: Me funcionó las indicaciones de [este link](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/caching-http-requests-with-angular/#:~:text=In%20an%20angular%20application%20the,for%20caching%20the%20HTTP%20requests.https://)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que deseaba hacer está descrito aquí (lo pongo por si ayuda en un futuro a alguien más): https://blog.fullstacktraining.com/caching-http-requests-with-angular/

Gracias a Pablo Lozano que con su comentario me guío hacia aquí.

Comment: Link visitado a la actualidad: Octubre 23, 2023. Link Roto :: Respuesta nula. Para evitar este tipo de situaciones, siempre realicen alguna extracción de código de ejemplo que sea independiente del link. Saludos.